# SSRS export to excel with multiple tabs and one report table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that has a simple table. I need 5 tabs in an excel export. Each tab will have the same table just filtered on one field in the dataset. Do I have to create 5 copies of the table and place page breaks etc to populate each tab, or is there a way of producing the 5 tabs using one table? If changes need to be made to the report, I would rather avoid making changes to 5 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce 5 tabs with one table if you have 5 unique values in your field. Create a new row grouping in your table on the field you want the filter (keep table structure the same), go to Group Properties for the group and there is a page break option for you to include a page break "between each instance of a group". This will break your pages up into individual sheets per group when you export it. However, if you have more than 5 different values in that field then you will have one sheet per unique value.

The other option you mentioned as well is to have one table per filter and manually put your filter in those tables. Then add page breaks before/after those tables.

The method you use can be based on your business requirements. If the users wish to see one tab per unique field value, then go with the first option. If the users wish to see only 5 tabs, first 4 tabs with top 4 occurrences and 5th tab is "all other values", then go with the second option.

Comment: The first option papermoon suggests is the way to go (personally). You can also change the expression in the group properties `Pagename` property. The result of this expression will be the name of the tab in Excel. For example, if your outer group was by Department and expression like `=Fields!Dept.Value` would name each tab with the content of the department name.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks for the extra info regarding naming of the tabs. The answer and your comment have given me exactly what was required.

Comment: @AlanSchofield is it possible to hide a column based on the row group value? For one of the 5 tables, one of the columns is not needed.

Comment: You can but you will get a blank space, it won't, as far as I know, collapse the column as you would expect

Answer (score -1):

The export function is just going to export whatever is visible in the report, so if you want 5 tables/tabs then you'll need to display those in the report.

One way around this could be to have 5 tables and have their visibility dependent on a variable which has a default value of False. You would then have a button/image on the report which is clicked, which is linked to the same report, but using URL access parameters and set the variable to true and the format to Excel.

This would make the export have the 5 tables, but is a rather horrible workaround.